# Get current_user number in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, so this might be too simple question. There is a :number column in users table. I want to get that number in User model for the current_user, then multiply it by another number(50 in this example) and use the resulting number to validate another number field(price) in Item model.

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :items

  def self.current
    Thread.current[:user]
  end

  def self.current=(user)
    Thread.current[:user] = user
  end

def method
  <Current User number> * 50
end
```

Item model

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true, :greater_than => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => (User.method) }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def max_num
    number * 50
  end
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true, 
                                    greater_than: 0,
                                    less_than_or_equal_to: :user_max_num }

  def user_max_num
    user.max_num
  end
end
```